# CatBoostClassifier static order of features

Tags: python, machine-learning, catboost

I fit the CatBoost model on the Titanic dataset from Kaggle:

```
train_df = pd.read_csv('input/train.csv')
test_df = pd.read_csv('input/test.csv')

train_df.fillna(-999, inplace=True)
test_df.fillna(-999, inplace=True)

x = train_df.drop('Survived', axis=1)
y = train_df.Survived

cate_features_index = np.where(x.dtypes != float)[0]

xtrain, xtest, ytrain, ytest = train_test_split(x, y, train_size=.85, random_state=1234)

model = CatBoostClassifier(eval_metric='Accuracy', use_best_model=True, random_seed=42)

model.fit(xtrain, ytrain, cat_features=cate_features_index, eval_set=(xtest, ytest))
```

The code works fine if my object has the same features order as `train_df`:

```
{
      "PassengerId": "892",
      "Pclass": "3",
      "Name": "Kelly, Mr. James",
      "Sex": "female",
      "Age": "34.5",
      "SibSp": "0",
      "Parch": "0",
      "Ticket": "330911",
      "Fare": "7.8292",
      "Cabin": "",
      "Embarked": "Q",
    }
```

But if I change order for example:

```
{
      "Age": "34.5",
      "Cabin": "",
      "Embarked": "Q",
      "Fare": "7.8292",
      "Name": "Kelly, Mr. James",
      "Parch": "0",
      "PassengerId": "892",
      "Pclass": "3",
      "Sex": "female",
      "SibSp": "0",
      "Ticket": "330911"
    }
```

I get an error

```
_catboost.CatBoostError: Bad value for num_feature[non_default_doc_idx=0,feature_idx=4]="Kelly, Mr. James": Cannot convert 'b'Kelly, Mr. James'' to float
```

Is it possible to fit the model without required features order?

Answer (score 3):

You can specify the categorical features using their names instead of their indices, in which case their order in the data frame will not matter.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from catboost import CatBoostClassifier

# import the data
df_train = pd.read_csv('train.csv')
df_test = pd.read_csv('test.csv')

# extract the features and target
X = df_train.drop('Survived', axis=1)
y = df_train['Survived']

# extract the names of the categorical features
cat_features = X.columns[np.where(X.dtypes != float)[0]].values.tolist()
print(cat_features)
# ['PassengerId', 'Pclass', 'Name', 'Sex', 'SibSp', 'Parch', 'Ticket', 'Cabin', 'Embarked']

# make sure that the categorical features are encoded as strings
X[cat_features] = X[cat_features].astype(str)

# split the data
X_train, X_valid, y_train, y_valid = train_test_split(X, y, train_size=0.85, random_state=1234)

# train the model
model = CatBoostClassifier(eval_metric='Accuracy', use_best_model=True, random_seed=1234)
model.fit(X_train, y_train, cat_features=cat_features, eval_set=(X_valid, y_valid))

print('Best Iteration: {}'.format(model.best_iteration_))
print('Training Accuracy: {:.2%}'.format(model.best_score_['learn']['Accuracy']))
print('Validation Accuracy: {:.2%}'.format(model.best_score_['validation']['Accuracy']))
# Best Iteration: 347
# Training Accuracy: 96.96%
# Validation Accuracy: 85.07%

# generate the model predictions
df_test[cat_features] = df_test[cat_features].astype(str)
y_pred = model.predict(df_test)
print(y_pred)
# [0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 . . . 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 1]
```

Comment: As an additional note, CatBoost supports passing features' names, so you don't have to worry about the categorical indices!